# can a fake AP have password?

Tags: wifi

I cannot speak English well, sorry.

What happens if we create a fake AP with linset on kali linux and we disconnect the target. He would then connect to our AP and when he wants to go to a site he will see a fake page that we created where we display the message: "please enter your wifi password"

But I think that is a kind of useless. If we could put the password on the fake AP, then what? I mean when target wants to connect to fake AP in the list of wifi, at that time it says "Password is required" without the fake page. He would enter his password and we see the password (a little bit like sniffing).

*Editor's Note:*
It is possible I have misrepresented the OP's question. Please stand by while the languages sync.

Comment: S4soriN - we can't understand what you are trying to do here. Can you clarify what you are wanting to get - as per @schroeder's comment.

Comment: By "password" are you talking about the WPA2 encryption key needed to connect, or a code that the user needs to enter at a webpage after connecting in order to access the Internet (as in a captive portal)?

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that the purpose of a fake AP is to collect the password of the real AP. That is incorrect. The purpose of the fake AP is to get the target's password to websites, like their email, bank, etc.

You disconnect the target from the real AP, connect them to you (without password), then as they go to their websites, you "sniff" their credentials.

Comment: No ... You're wrong ...  i dont want to sniff or ... some one ... i mean sniffing there wifi password not gmail or some other account ... If you've worked with wifislax ... there is an tool name linset ... You would know what I mean. tnx

Comment: Then I am very confused. You want to know their wifi password? Then configure the fake AP to accept any password the target sends and simply record what they send. Why do you want the wifi password?

Comment: I really can say i know a lot of way to find wifi pass : crack-hanshake-MITM-WPS-Fake page and etc. finding other way can be Creativity ... and just for Learning and fun ... tnx