# fake ap with password

Tags: wifi

I cannot speak English well, sorry.

What happens if we create a fake AP with linset on kali linux and we disconnect the target. He would then connect to our AP and when he wants to go to a site he will see a fake page that we created where we display the message: "please enter your wifi password"

But I think that is a kind of useless. If we could put the password on the fake AP, then what? I mean when target wants to connect to fake AP in the list of wifi, at that time it says "Password is required" without the fake page. He would enter his password and we see the password (a little bit like sniffing).

Comment: Please don't re-ask questions that have already been put on hold: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85921/can-a-fake-ap-have-password